# Linear programming with many variables and parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to reconstruct the answer that is given in [this report](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a332296.pdf). (page 153 in Appendix B; Section B.2.1). They are given variables, parameters, constraints, and the objective function to minimize.

Summary of the problem:

```
Minimize: q01 + q11 + q21 + q31 - q02 - q12 - q22 - q32
Variables: {q00 , q01 , q02 , q03 , q10 , q11 , q12 , q13 , 
            q20 , q21 , q22 , q23 , q30, q31 , q32 , q33}
Parameters: {p000 , p010 , p100 , p110 , p001 , p011 , p101 , p111}
Constraints: 
  1) all q's nonnegative
  2) [sum all q's] == 1
  3) p000 == q00 + q01 + q10 + q11
  4) p010 == q20 + q22 + q30 + q32
  5) p100 == q02 + q03 + q12 + q13
  6) p110 == q21 + q23 + q31 + q33
  7) p001 == q00 + q01 + q20 + q21
  8) p011 == q10 + q12 + q30 + q32
  9) p101 == q02 + q03 + q22 + q23
  10) p111 == q11 + q13 + q31 + q33
```

Their output is given on page 155 as the maximum of a set of eight linear functions of the parameters:

```
 Minimum of Objective Function is the Maximum of:
 p111 + p000 - 1
 p110 + p001 - 1
 -p011 - p101
 -p010 - p100
 p110 - p111 - p101 - p010 - p100
 p111 - p110 - p100 - p011 - p101
 p001 - p011 - p101 - p010 - p000
 p000 - p010 - p100 - p011 - p001
```

When trying to reproduce it in *Mathematica* 8.0, first tried simple test case of using parameters

```
LinearProgramming[{1, 1}, {{1, 2}}, {a}]
```

which gave an error, but using Minimize does give a full answer

```
Minimize[x + y, x + 2*y >= a && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {x, y}]
```

I then rephrased the original problem in terms of Minimize function and even after running overnight it was still thinking:

```
Minimize[q01 + q11 + q21 + q31 - q02 - q12 - q22 - q32, 
  q00 + q01 + q02 + q03 + q10 + q11 + q12 + q13 + q20 + q21 + q22 + 
    q23 + q30 + q31 + q32 + q33 == 1 && 
  q00 >= 0 && q01 >= 0 && 
  q02 >= 0 && q03 >= 0 && q10 >= 0 && q11 >= 0 && q12 >= 0 && 
  q13 >= 0 && q20 >= 0 && q21 >= 0 && q22 >= 0 && q23 >= 0 && 
  q30 >= 0 && q31 >= 0 && q32 >= 0 && q33 >= 0 && 
  p000 == q00 + q01 + q10 + q11 && p010 == q20 + q22 + q30 + q32 && 
  p100 == q02 + q03 + q12 + q13 && p110 == q21 + q23 + q31 + q33 && 
  p001 == q00 + q01 + q20 + q21 && p011 == q10 + q12 + q30 + q32 && 
  p101 == q02 + q03 + q22 + q23 && 
  p111 == q11 + q13 + q31 + q33, {q00, q01, q02, q03, q10, q11, q12, 
  q13, q20, q21, q22, q23, q30, q31, q32, q33}]
```

Is there a way for *Mathematica* (8.0) to reproduce their results? Have a feeling I'm either missing a function that would answer it, or not inputting some restriction or assumption which Mathematica needs. Thank you!

#### EDIT

I tried the suggestion of @Anon:

```
Minimize[{f, constraints}, {q00, q02, ...}]
```

instead of

```
Minimize[f, constraints, {q00, q01, ...}]
```

hoping that was the answer. It still was thinking overnight, with no answer produced. Is Minimize the correct function to use for this problem?

*(Originally posted in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909005/linear-programming-with-parameters), first response recommended posting the question here)*

Comment: The syntax is `Minimize[{f,constraints},{q00,q02...}]` and it looks like you wrote `Minimize[f,constraint,{q00,q01...}]`.

Comment: @Anon          Thanks for the correction. However, when I tried that procedure it still did not produce an answer, even after thinking overnight.

Comment: I'm not much good with these things but I'd like to help if I can.  Could you provide an example smaller than the main one but larger than `Minimize[x + y, x + 2*y >= a && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {x, y}]` that *can* be solved by `Minimize`?

Comment: @sheppa28 If one removes all constraints but the first, `q00 + q01 + q02 + q03 + q10 + q11 + q12 + q13 + q20 + q21 + q22 + 
    q23 + q30 + q31 + q32 + q33 == 1`, `Minimize` quickly returns "The minimum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints." Piling on more constraints isn't helping I suppose, maybe it's taking so long because there are lots of combinations to try and no correct answer. (IDK any about this, I just put this to you for consideration.)

Comment: Note the problem is not solvable for "arbitrary" parameters, for one thing all p must obviously be > 0. Its likely getting bogged down generating massive lists of conditional results for different p cases.  Adding all pxx>=0 to the system might help..

Comment: @george2079 Isn't pxxx>=0 implied by the their equality and [all q's]>=0? Would adding additional implied constraints help? (honest question). For 'arbitrary' parameters, given the constraints listed, it is solvable in closed form - which is given above. It occurred to me today that one way they may have done it was to take the dual, this way the possible solutions are linear combinations of the parameters (pxxx's). This then turns it into finding the eight combinations listed above. (And the max of them is the min of objective function)

Comment: the point is its not implied, they are unspecified parameters. If mathematica found the solution it would be of the form `If[ p111>0 && p000 >0 && ... &&  p111 + p000  >  p110 + p001  ...  , p111 + p000 - 1 ] ..` nested 8 levels (assuming the reported solution is correct..)

Comment: continuing.. one thing I tried to no avail was to force a particular solution by adding 7 more inequalities based on the claimed solution, ie. `p111 + p000 - 1 >  p110 + p001 - 1` (with each p replaced by its sum of q's definition.). That might be worth persuing if you only want to verify the solution .. I didnt let it work overnight...

Comment: The solution in the original paper rests on the enumeration of the extreme points of the polyhedral feasible set of qij's but it does not give that set (as far as I can see). This is why you are having problems retracing the solution. In general, enumerating the extreme points is a hard problem (google "polytope vertex enumeration"). However here the Linear Program is very small and there may be some structure that the original authors exploited. I am not sure the suggestion to move here from the math forum was the best.

Answer (score 2):

`LinearProgramming` will work but you need the values for the parameters as it is not a symbolic algorithm.

Constructing the parameters for `LinearProgramming` will give:

```
c = Flatten@{{1, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1, 0}};
```

This corresponds to the minimisation problem. I use the matrix form and then flatten to assist with translating.  The left-hand side of the constraints in the same order as you have present will give:

```
m =
  {
   ConstantArray[1, 16],
   Flatten@{{1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}},
   Flatten@{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}},
   Flatten@{{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}},
   Flatten@{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}},
   Flatten@{{1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}},
   Flatten@{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}},
   Flatten@{{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}},
   Flatten@{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}
  };
```

The right-hand side of the constraints is where you need values for the algorithm to compute.  I've chosen some values that will work for all but the first constraint.  I hand to change the first constraint from `== 1` to `>= 1` to demonstrate that it works.  You need the actual values from the constraints to get the intended result since `LinearProgramming` is not a symbolic algorithm.

```
p000 = 0.9; p010 = 0.8; p100 = 0.7; p110 = 0.6; 
p001 = 0.5; p011 = 0.6; p101 = 0.8; p111 = 0.9;
b = {{1, 1}, {p000, 0}, {p010, 0}, {p100, 0}, {p110, 0}, 
     {p001, 0}, {p011, 0}, {p101, 0}, {p111, 0}};
```

This will solve but as I don't have the actual values to the parameters and had to change the first constraint from `==` to `>=` the result vector sums to 3 instead of 1.

```
LinearProgramming[c, m, b]
(* {0., 0.3, 0.7, 0., 0., 0.6, 0., 0., 0.2, 0.2, 0., 0.1, 0., 0., 0.6, 0.3} *)
Total[%]
(* 3 *)
```

This returns immediately; no overnight wait. I suspect that if you get the actual parameter values (and change the first constraint back to `==` by changing the `{1,1}` to `{1,0}` in `b`) that it would solve equally as fast.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Removing the >= 0 constrains solves the problem

```
q00 >= 0 && q01 >= 0 && 
q02 >= 0 && q03 >= 0 && q10 >= 0 && q11 >= 0 && q12 >= 0 && 
q13 >= 0 && q20 >= 0 && q21 >= 0 && q22 >= 0 && q23 >= 0 && 
q30 >= 0 && q31 >= 0 && q32 >= 0 && q33 >= 0 &&
```

-

```
Minimize[{q01 + q11 + q21 + q31 - q02 - q12 - q22 - q32,

  q00 + q01 + q02 + q03 + q10 + q11 + q12 + q13 + q20 + q21 + q22 + 
     q23 + q30 + q31 + q32 + q33 == 1 &&
   p000 - q00 - q01 - q10 - q11 == 0 &&
   p010 - q20 - q22 - q30 - q32 == 0 &&
   p100 - q02 - q03 - q12 - q13 == 0 &&
   p110 - q21 - q23 - q31 - q33 == 0 &&
   p001 - q00 - q01 - q20 - q21 == 0 &&
   p011 - q10 - q12 - q30 - q32 == 0 &&
   p101 - q02 - q03 - q22 - q23 == 0 &&
   p111 - q11 - q13 - q31 - q33 == 0
  },
 {q00, q01, q02, q03, q10, q11, q12, q13, q20, q21, q22, q23, q30, q31, q32, q33}]
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Removing the >= constraints does solve the run-time problem, but the answers do not match. Is there a way to reconstruct their answer? (Given above in original question under "Minimum of Objective Function is the Maximum of:")  On a side note, when all the p's are specified numerically Mathematica does give the correct numerical answer, along with what the q's equal. I am trying to reproduce the parametric solution given in the original paper.